# App crashes on iOS5 after dealloc

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have a problem running an app on iOS 5 which works fine on iOS 4.3. I havnt converted the project to ARC so ARC should be completely disabled and as far as I understood the app should run like it always has with manual reference counting? It is currently crashing after the dealloc method (after [super dealloc] has been called), more precicely it gets a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this part:

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); //EXC_BAD_ACCESS

[pool release];

return retVal;
```

}

I have tried to convert to ARC, but this is currently not possible as a I have third party JSON library which is unsupported. I have tried to put the compiler flag on all the appropriate files:

-fno-objc-arc

However this doesnt make any difference when trying the convert into ARC as the same errors appear as before and furthermore Xcode removes the flags from the files after the failed attempt.

Does anyone know what is going on here? I would assume if ARC is disabled then calls such as release should be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I was setting the class as a delegate of something else, the problem was resolved when I set the delegate to nil in the dealloc method. This was completely ignored in iOS4, but seems like iOS5 is more sensitive to these things. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a framework change from iOS 4 to iOS 5.0 means that you're hitting a dangling pointer. The EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in `main` is usually a sign of an object in the autorelease pool already being dealloced i.e. it has been over released or under retained.

I came across this same issue with UIImagePickerController in one of my projects.

Zombies are a good way to investigate autorelease problems. To turn on Zombies in Xcode 4.1 or 4.2 there's a checkbox on the "Diagnostics" tab of the "Run" stage called "Enable Zombie Objects".

With Zombies enabled when you should get an exception in the console where you were previously hitting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. This exception will tell you information about the object.

Comment: I enabled the zombie and get the following error:

-[MagazineImageView isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6ad8150

So it seems like the object was already released? I just cant really see where this should happen differently in iOS5 than in iOS4.

if I remove the [super dealloc] the crash doesn't happen..

Comment: iOS 5.0 saw some big optimisations to the objective c runtime so code that didn't follow proper memory management and "worked" on iOS 4.0 won't necessarily work on iOS 5.0. You know that MagazineImageView is the object that is being over released so perhaps override -(void)release { [super release]; }, -(id)autorelease { return [super autorelease]; }, -(id)retain { return [super retain]; }  and break point them. You'll then be able to look up the stack trace and see where you've overreleased or under retained.

Comment: I tried that and found out it crashes right after 
-[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
Im still not sure where the over releasing is happening, I even managed to convert the project into ARC and the same thing is happening..

Comment: @mackross How did you resolve the issue w/ UIImagePickerController?